# how do I use a downloaded image on a embed with discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to remove the image link where it says ".setImage" and replace that with a downloaded image  how would I go about that?

```
    /** @format */
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports = new Command({
    name: "Cookie",
    description: "sends a image",
    permission: "SEND_MESSAGES", 
    async run(message, args, client) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed
            .setTitle("here is your cookie")
            .setDescription(
                "photo discription"
            )
            .setColor("BLURPLE")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setImage(
                "https://assets.bonappetit.com/photos/5ca534485e96521ff23b382b/1:1/w_2700,h_2700,c_limit/chocolate-chip-cookie.jpg"
            )
        message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Canvas in embed Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593921/send-canvas-in-embed-discord-js) or [How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199950/how-do-i-use-a-local-image-on-a-discord-js-rich-embed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a imagehost like [Imgur](https://www.imgur.com) to upload your downloaded image and get the image url of it, and use that url in your `.setImage()` method, you can also use another imagehost, just use what u like :)

**EDIT:**

It's also possible to do it without a link or imagehost, here is an example:

```js
const image = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./path/to/image.png', 'attachement-name.png')

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed
            .setTitle("here is your cookie")
            .setDescription(
                "photo discription"
            )
            .setColor("BLURPLE")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setImage(
                "attachment://attachement-name.png"
            )
        message.reply({ embeds: [embed], files: [image] });
```

Comment: You should show a code example of how do this.

Comment: Its just put the url in the method as string like he did with his old url, what do you mean code example? 

Comment: Show how to do this programmatically. Don’t just say to use a site. Show how to connect and get the link too.

Comment: Everyone knows how to use Imgur I think, I'm not going to waste my time explaining Imgur again step by step, but if you know better go ahead and post your own :)